# One command to do make and run in c++?

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

I was doing debugging for homework. I had to type make and ./a2 billions of times just to see my stuff drawn on the screen.

**I use vim and a shell**

I m sure there must be a way(script) to just press one button and do "make" and ./a2 at the same time

What is this command?

What **cool hack/trick** do you use to avoid some repetitive typing?

Comment: `make && ./a2`?  Alternatively, make use of reverse history search in `bash`: `Ctrl+R` then `make` would bring up the last command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using shell how about

```
make && ./a2
```

You can always just write a script to deploy. Or, why not use an IDE? Eclipse for C++ is free.

Answer (score 3):

add a "test" pseudo-target to your makefile:

```
.PHONY: test # instruct make to always "build" the following target
test: ./a2
        ./a2
```

Now you can simply run `make test` in command line. If you copy the lines above, make sure that the recepy line starts with a <kbd>tab</kbd> character.

Comment: what is .PHONY? a special keyword? macros?

Comment: [.PHONY](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) was designed to epress the difference between "real" targets, like file `a2`, and "phony", virtual targets, that don't represent files; it instructs **make** to always _build_ the target, not check if file `./test` is up-to-date. I added this line for two reasons: to guarantee that a accidental file named `test` in the current directory will not prevent `./a2` to run, and so that the intent be more explicit, kind of self-documented code.